# How to share content for facebook and twitter from react app

Tags: reactjs, laravel, server-side-rendering

I have a frontend built in Reactjs and a backend in Laravel. Both are on the same server. I have a feature of Social Share for Facebook and Twitter. As both reads informations from meta tags provided in the head tag while sharing.

So my question is how to share information from a specific page (component) of frontend when its content gets changed.

I googled on this. It is being advised to use Server Side Rendering for this.

Is there any alternative for this to achieve or How to do with SSR then?

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

You can try Pre-render. But I recommend SSR

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I don't know how to use SSR. Can you guide me.